# How to pass variable content to a parameter value in dart/flutter?

Tags: oop, flutter, dart

I may be missing something obvious, but I'm having trouble passing a variable to a parameter or widget in flutter/dart. For example, let's say I have some variable:

`String col = 'red';`

and I want to pass this to a color parameter to get the equivalent of

```
color: Colors.red
```

The difficult thing is that any way I try to pass the value ends up passing a string (which isn't accepted), including trying to pass just the value of `col` directly or trying to build a function that returns `Colors.col`.

I think what I need is something like a function like

```
setColor(String str) {
    return Colors.str;
  }
```

but, as you might expect, this returns "The getter 'str' isn't defined for the type 'Colors'." (And similarly for:

```
setColor(String str) {
    return Colors.$str;
}
```

I know one option is to create a function using a bunch of if's, like

```
setColor(String str) {
 if (str==red) return Colors.red;
 if (str==blue) return Colors.blue;
 if (str==green) return Colors.green;
etc.
}
```

but I'd prefer a more elegant option if one is available.

EDIT: It looks like this isn't quite as easy as I'd hoped (see answers and comments to answers below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library [Supercharged](https://pub.dev/packages/supercharged) is your best solution. You can try it this way (Hex text or HTML color):

```
"#ff00ff".toColor();  // pink
"ff0000".toColor();   // red
"00f".toColor();      // blue
"red".toColor();      // red (HTML color name)
"deeppink".toColor(); // deep pink (HTML color name)
```

Of course, this function depends on extension. Extension methods, introduced in Dart 2.7.

Edit:

```
extension MainAxisAlignmentExtension on String {
  MainAxisAlignment get mainAxis {
    switch (this.toUpperCase()) {
      case "BETWEEN":
        return MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween;
      case "AROUND":
        return MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround;
      case "EVENLY":
        return MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly;
      case "CENTER":
        return MainAxisAlignment.center;
      case "START":
        return MainAxisAlignment.start;
      case "END":
        return MainAxisAlignment.end;
      default:
        return MainAxisAlignment.start;
    }
  }
}

print("Between".mainAxis);
print("AROUND".mainAxis);
```

Comment: This looks promising for the color case - I'll have to try it out. In general though, is there no way to pass values of string to parameters? For example, say I wanted to define a widget MyRow that was composed of a row such that the mainAxisAlignment value was determined by a parameter of MyRow. Similar to my example here, I'd want to pass something like "around" or "Between" to get MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround or .spaceBetween.

Comment: Well, following the same extension approach I edit my answer to achieve that, although you'll have to do your own snippets to it. Please check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was just playing with SuperCharged and realized what you're referring to here, which is that this still required a function that contains an if clause for each case. I was hoping to avoid this, but it seems like this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing Color as String, you can use type Color

```
Color col = Colors.red;
```

If you want to continue using String to store color you can use the hex value

```
String col = "#FF5733";
```

And use a function to convert it to color

```
Color hexToColor(String code) {
  return new Color(int.parse(code.substring(1, 7), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000); 
}
```

Example:

```
Color newColor = hexToColor(col);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: I don't quite follow here. If the variable col can take multiple values ("red", "blue", etc.), I don't see how this can pass this value without knowing what it is ahead of time.

Comment: You will actually need a mechanism to convert the color as flutter doesn't know what is "red".So what I meant was instead of passing red you can pass hex codes of color and use the function to convert it to color. If you want to continue using "red", "green", what you can do is make a `Map<String, Color>` like `{"red":Colors.red}` and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass colors from one widget to another by declaring color as a variable.

```
final Color redColor=Colors.red;
```

Then you can pass it to a widget as an argument (Passing color to a widget):

```
Widget something(Color redColor){
 Text("It Works!",style: TextStyle(color: redColor))
}
```

If you want to pass it from one stateless or stateful widget to another:

```
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // Declare a field that holds the color.
  final Color redColor;

  // In the constructor, require a Color.
  DetailScreen({Key key, @required this.redColor}) : super(key: key);

  // Your widget build and other things here
}
```

Then get the value by calling:

```
Text("It Works!",style: TextStyle(color: widget.redColor))
```

Comment: This doesn't quite do what I need, I don't think. In general, I want to be able to define a (stateless) widget that takes a few parameters, and then uses these parameters to build itself. For example, I want to be able to call Widget(col: 'red') and then have it build a red version of itself with components that depend on the input. (Thus I could have it include widgets that have different numerical values of the same color - red[800], red[600], etc.) I hope this clarifies.

Comment: @Mik it is also answered above in Then you can pass it to a widget as an argument: Hope this helps :)

Comment: Right, but in this case I'll need to have individual variable definitions for each possible value of the color String, correct? Thus I need "if col==red then Color redColor=Colors.red; if col==blue then Color redColor=Colors.blue; etc.", don't I? (In this case I can create a function that does what I need, but I'm hoping to avoid this.) Thanks

Comment: @Mik As far as I know, there is no possible way to avoid what you are trying to avoid. In this case, you can use a switch statement to make your code cleaner and easier to read. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Mik You're Welcome. Please mark this as an answer so that it can help people who are having a similar problem. Thanks. You can also help me by upvoting on this answer.